# encoding error in clang + visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, clang

I've switched platform toolset in my project to "Clang 3.7 with Microsoft CodeGen (v140_clang_3_7)" in order to try out Clang. When I tried to build, I got this error:

```
1>clang.exe : error : unable to execute command: Unable to convert command-line to UTF-16
```

However, when I checked the command line options in project properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line, there are none non-ascii characters.

What is going on? If you need any more info then I'm happy to provide.

Comment: The intermediate build directory usually contains a `.log` file (at least for the Microsoft toolchain builds) - maybe you can see the exact failing line there? Looking at clang source it seems to be an innocent encoding conversion. Another cause could be if the command line exceeds MAX_PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, the logs had no more information than that in compiler output. After thorough search, I found that the paths to the standard library inherited by the project contained a system directory name which had non-ascii characters due to my system locale. I'm afraid the only solution is to re-install Windows with en locale... :(

Comment: Maybe make a symlink to the VS include folder, remove all default include paths and use the symlink path? Then you could avoid reinstalling.